# Object already exists errors while restoring a clean pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore, postgresql-15

I am creating pg dump of a database using following command:

```
pg_dump mydatabase -Fc -c -U mydatabaseuser -f mydatabase_pgdump_$(date +^CY%m%dT%H%M")
```

Then  i am trying to to restore that dump using following:

```
pg_restore -d mydatabase -U postgres mydatabase_pgdump_20230422T0540
```

However, this gives me a lot of object `already exists` errors, such as:

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "user_token" already exists
```

The destination database is already there, however I have include `-c --clean` in my `pg_dump` command, so shouldn't all the existing object first dropped and then recreated? Or i am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the docs:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

> -c
> --clean

> Output commands to clean (drop) database objects prior to outputting the commands for creating them. (Unless --if-exists is also specified, restore might generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not present in the destination database.)

> This option is ignored when emitting an archive (non-text) output file. For the archive formats, you can specify the option when you call pg_restore.

Note the last section. If you want `-c` to take effect you will need to add it to the `pg_restore` as:

`pg_restore -c -d mydatabase -U postgres mydatabase_pgdump_20230422T0540`

Answer (score 0):

Some database objects you are restoring might exist, so try dropping them manually before restoring. Something like:

```
DROP DATABASE db_name
```

OR

```
DROP SCHEMA schame_name
```

might work.

You need to clean it properly & restore it to empty database.

Comment: This is not an answer to the issue. `-c` will clean the objects out when specified in the proper place.